# SignalR Hub - Authenticate users, but allow anonymous users too

Tags: c#, authorization, signalr

I use JWT Bearer tokens for my application - simple chat on my site. Chat users can be logged in and not logged in. To use chat, you can be logged or not.
(Logged in users can receive private messages and so on).

This means that there may be users in my hub with or without an account (AspNetUser) in the system.

I correctly identify users using `Context.Users`. SignalR connects connectionId to userId (and other logged in user information). To make it happen, I decided to insert an `Authorization` filter. When I don't include this filter, **the hub sees all users as anonymous**.

I would like my hub was able to service all connections (logged in or anonymous users). Currently, due to the `[Authorize]` attribute, only logged in users can use my hub. Anonymous users receive a 401 error.
The below method should explain what I want to achieve:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OAuthIntrospectionDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{  
      public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
      {
         string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.User.Identity.Name))
         {
            Console.WriteLine($"New Connection! It's a registered user: {name}!");
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine($"New Connection! It's an anonymous user!");
         }

         return base.OnConnectedAsync();
      }
}
```

**Why do I need it?**
All users receive the same public messages. However, a private message can be sent to logged in users. I do it as follows (and only appropriate user receive this message):

```
Clients.User("userId").SendAsync("Message", "Something");
```

Is it possible for my hub to treat users like:

- "Are you logged in? That's nice, I'll save your details."
- "Are you not logged in? Don't worry, you're welcome too, but I'll save only a connection ID and nothing else about you).

Comment: I believe that you can "login" all users as anonymous users and then specified the users as anonymous and not. Then you just implement the autorization like in the documentation, where each hub method has a authorize attribute for a specified policy user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#authorize-users-to-access-hubs-and-hub-methods

Comment: I'm not sure what is the layout and logic of your web pages. But you could have a login page where the user has the option to effectively log in or skip this step. Both actions would redirect you to the chat page, the difference being the existence of an active Context.User in one case and not on the other case. Your Hub class wouldn't have the [Authorize] attribute. Any user (logged in or anonymous) would be able to send a generic message, which would call, let's say, a SendMessage method in which you would call Clients.All.SendAsync (I'll break this comment in 2 due to char limit).

Comment: If the message is supposed to be directed to a specific user, in the SendMessage method check the Context.User to see if the sender is an authenticated user or not. If not, the message is not sent. The SendMessage signature could be something like SendMessage (string user, string message). If user == null, the message is directed to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add [AllowAnonymous] to your hub.

This code is working for me with ASP.NET Core SignalR:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
```

Comment: does not work with windows-integrated auth :(

Comment: This didn't work for me. If I add `[AllowAnonymous]` my auth handler *will* be called, but even though I call `AuthenticateResult.Success`, the hub still sees the user as unauthenticated.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your code, I would suggest you change:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.User.Identity.Name))
```

To:

```
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

The MSDN documentation does not make it obvious (at a glance) but 'SignalR' has it's own (same-name) 'Authorize' attribute; so if you derive from it, you can override the following method (within your custom/derived version - e.g. "SignalRAuthorizeAttribute"):

```
        public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(
                                        IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext,
                                        bool appliesToMethod)
        {
            if (hubIncomingInvokerContext.MethodDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<SignalRAllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any() ||
                hubIncomingInvokerContext.MethodDescriptor.Hub.HubType.GetCustomAttributes<SignalRAllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any())
            {
                return true;
            }

            return
                base.AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(
                        hubIncomingInvokerContext,
                        appliesToMethod);
        }
```

And therefore you can have your hubs closed by default (so that the exceptional anonymous one/s have to be actively whitelisted with a custom 'SignalRAllowAnonymousAttribute' attribute):

```
            // GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();

            var authorizeAttribute =
                new SignalRAuthorizeAttribute();

            GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(
                new AuthorizeModule(
                    globalConnectionAuthorizer: authorizeAttribute,
                    globalInvocationAuthorizer: authorizeAttribute));
```

```
    // Marker class
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class SignalRAllowAnonymousAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
```